# Passing variables to SSH

Tags: shell, ssh

The following code loops through states in a array and passes a state to a server via ssh -

```
STATES="NY CO"

arr_states=(${STATES//' /'/ })

for i in "${arr_states[@]}"; do
  state=$i
  
  ssh -o SendEnv=state jenkins@server sh -s << 'EOF'
  sudo su
  cd /home/jenkins/report

  psql -d db -c "$(sed 's/state_name/'"$state"'/' county.sql)" -U user

  echo $state

EOF

done
```

The output of `echo $state` in the above is an empty string even if I pass it `NY`.

When I change the `'EOF'` to `EOF`, the output of `echo $state` is the string I passed (`NY`). But then it says, the file `county.sql` does not exist.

How do I get it to recognize both the variable I pass and the file on the remote I am trying to run.

Comment: Really need to show us what STATES has in it.

Comment: It's definitely not correct - try settings states to this `arr_states=( CO NY )` - that gives the sort of output you are expecting (where _$state_ has a value).

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use `sh -s` instead of `bash -s`? Many of bash's mechanisms to programatically generate code that's safe to execute only work if the receiving shell is also bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an approach that doesn't require you to do any manual escaping of your code (which frequently becomes a maintenance nightmare, since it means that code needs to be changed whenever you modify where it's expected to run) -- consider defining a function, and using `declare -f` to ask the shell to generate code that will output that function for you.

The same can be done with variables, using `declare -p`. Thus, passing both a function with the remote code, and the variables that remote code needs to operate that way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This is run on the remote server _as root_ (behind sudo su)
remotePostEscalationFunc() {
  cd /home/jenkins/report || return
  if psql -d db -U user -c "$(sed -e "s/state_name/${state}/" county.sql)"; then
    echo "Success processing $state" >&2
  else
    rc=$?
    echo "Failure processing $state" >&2
    return "$rc"
  fi
}

# This is run on the remote server as the jenkins user (before sudo).
remoteFunc() {
  sudo su -c "$(declare -p state); $(declare -f remotePostEscalationFunc); remotePostEscalationFunc"
}

# Everything below here is run locally.

arr_states=( NY CO )

for state in "${arr_states[@]}"; do
  ssh jenkins@server 'bash -s' <<EOF
$(declare -f remoteFunc remotePostEscalationFunc); $(declare -p state); remoteFunc
EOF
done
```

Comment: This is written beautifully! The only issue I am having with this is - 

When I add `psql -d db -U user -c "COPY public.tab (npi, va_pct, commercial_pct, other_pct) FROM '/tmp/data.tab' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"` statement to the `remoteFunc` I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: It'll make things a bit easier if we split the things that need privilege escalation into a separate function, so the shell can do even more escaping for us instead of needing to do it ourselves. I'll be sitting at my desk in an hour or so and will take a shot at it then.

Comment: Thank you! The statement above is something we need the remote shell to do.

Comment: See the edit -- I didn't add your change in since it wasn't in the question, but anything you write in `remotePostEscalationFunc`'s definition can use the exact same syntax you could use on the remote system's command line, with no changes to quoting/escaping/etc needed.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right with the change from `'EOF'` to `EOF`. You are just missing a backslash (`\`) before `$(sed`. So the following should work:

```
arr_states=(${STATES//' /'/ })

for i in "${arr_states[@]}"; do
  state=$i
  
  ssh -o SendEnv=state jenkins@server sh -s << EOF
  sudo su
  cd /home/jenkins/report

  psql -d db -c "\$(sed 's/state_name/'"$state"'/' county.sql)" -U user

  echo $state

EOF

done
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Can you explain what backslash is doing and why it fixes the issue?

Comment: @Aaron, the backslash stops the local shell from running the expansion before the code gets to the remote shell at all.